# Need to automate kill wpa_supplicant on resume on 15.04 with systemd

Tags: scripts, 15.04, systemd, wpa-supplicant

I need to run

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

automatically after resume.
Unfortunately on 15.04 with systemd it isn't possible with scripts.

How this may be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your scripts in:

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

An example script based on one from the Arch wiki  ([systemd sleep Hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Hooks_in_.2Fusr.2Flib.2Fsystemd.2Fsystem-sleep)):

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    # better to put `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    # Add whatever you want run post suspend (ie resume)
    killall wpa_supplicant
    ;;
esac
```

Dont forget to make your script executable!

```
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/your-script
```

See `man systemd-sleep` for more details.

There is no need for `sudo` as your script will be run as root.

Comment: I did all as recommended: created script, saved it to system-sleep dir and chmod to executable.

Did not helped. Wifi did not enabled. By the way invoking `sudo killall wpa_supplicant` manually from command line still helps.

Comment: I can only offer guesses. Grep syslog of the message "Waking up from" which should be from systemd-sleep.  If you see this message start playing around to see what is going on. for example put `ps aux > /tmp/testps` or something after `echo "waking...` to see if wpa_supplicant is running. Maybe you need to sleep for a few seconds first, start high adding `sleep 10s` before `killall wpasupplicant`.

Comment: Adding `sleep 10s` is a good idea. I am trying it now. Thanks!

Comment: Works! Now it works as expected. I've set 6s sleep time and for my case it solves.